# Tablet Bluetooth Keyboard Fn Lock Not Working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, tablet

I bought a tablet case with a bluetooth keyboard.
The keyboard has media keys enabled by default, instead of <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys.
I would like to swap that and have the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys enabled by default (not having to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> every time).

For example, I have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open help.

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> lock key is on the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key (it has a little lock icon underneath it and there is no  other locks in all the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys, nor the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, so it has to be the one). Unfortunately it does not work.
I have tried <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> but it will not change the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys behavior nor display anything (pressing <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, for example, shows a brief caps lock overlay on screen)

Unfortunately there is no manufacturer or model on the keyboard so I can not do a specific Google search (it came with a 3rd-party tablet case I bought)

Just to make sure, keyboard drivers are up to date (according to Windows' automatic driver search at least), and tablet is a Lenovo running Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried Shift + Del to enable Fn lock-ing?

Comment: The setting for this may well be configurable in the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately there's no Fn Lock setting in the BIOS (I checked) and shift+del did not enable Fn Lock

Answer (score 0):

mine had ios/android/windows mode switching on fn+q/w/e buttons. Changing mode to be windows while working with windows laptop works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).